# toggleClass() for resizing circle after Paper Ripple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-transitions, polymer

I'm trying to make a circle with the paper-ripple animation that when clicked, transitions to a much bigger circle. This exists on a very wide `<div>` that can be scrolled through with a button, rather than the scroll-bar.

HTML:

```
    <link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html">
<div class="main">
    <div id="hero">
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="background"></div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="disk">
                            <paper-ripple class="circle recenteringTouch" fit></paper-ripple>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="scrollButton">
                                         <span>&#10095;</span>
                                        <paper-ripple class=" circle recenteringTouch " fit></paper-ripple>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

I'm not sure if using a `<table>` is right; I just thought it would help organization.

JS:

```
    var disk = $('.disk');
disk.on("core-transitionend", function () {
    toggleClass("bigger");
});
```

CSS:

```
.disk {
-webkit-transition: width, height, 2s;
    -moz-transition: width, height, 2s;
    -o-transition: width, height, 2s;
    transition: width, height, 2s;
}

.bigger {
width:500px;
height:500px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ko2a57ux/1/)

Comment: $(this).toggleClass("bigger");

Comment: Thanks! I feel so stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to target `$(this)` in the handler for `core-transitionend`

```
disk.on("core-transitionend", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("bigger");
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/njvL62bw/)

Comment: Mohamed answered the same thing, but thanks anyways!